# Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: invalid ELF header

Tags: php

```
Message:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: invalid ELF header
```

I am getting error in my page got stuck with three days

Every thing tried but not able resolve

Comment: `.dll` are for Windows but the path `/usr/lib/php/...` is a nix-path. What OS are you running?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 linux server

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install php-curl` or `sudo apt install php7.2-curl`? Don't forget to restart the web server (if you're running apache) or php-fpm (if you're running that) after.

Comment: I'm also guessing that you've uncommented/added `extension=php_curl.dll` in your ini-file? You need to remove/comment out that line again.

Comment: yes I have again comment out those line where php_curl.dll was there but again showing the same error even after restarting server apache

Comment: Did you remove it from the correct ini file? There are two ini-files. One in `/etc/php/7.2/cli` and one in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2`. If you're running php-fpm instead of mod_php for apache, there could be a `/etc/php/7.2/fpm` as well. Then you also need to restart php-fpm: `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart`.

Comment: from cli I have uncomment

Comment: Ah. You need to do it in the /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini as well. That's the ini-file that is used when running apache.

Comment: oh thanks man Magnus Eriksson. Thanks a lot it works I think I just missed to comment it, Thanks a lot made my day

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to load *Windows* dynamic libraries **.dll** on a *Linux* OS. Linux has another binary format for dynamic libraries which are **.so**.